# Internet disconnects randomly on Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: networking, ethernet, connection

I've had this issue for a few months now. My desktop PC disconnects *randomly* up to 4 times a day for about 10 to 90 seconds. Here's a list of things I tried:

- use a different ethernet cable
- update network drivers
- get a new router
- use a dedicated network card (ethernet controller: Aquantia AQC107)
- manually set the DNS server (1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1)
- update UEFI BIOS
- numerous other fixes (I can't remember every little thing I tried honestly)

Other information regarding my system and setup:

- I have an ethernet cable going from the router directly to my PC
- I dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10, the issue exists on both operating systems.
- Motherboard ethernet controller: Intel I219-V
- Old and new routers are different models (old: Technicolor TC7230, new: Sagemcom F@ST3890)
- My PC is the only device in the household with this issue.
- Other devices using a lot of bandwidth do not seem to increase the frequency or duration of the disconnects.

I'm at my wits' end. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you change the DNS for IPv6? Did you contact your ISP and told them about your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for anyone stumbling across this question with the same problem.

I managed to finally get it **fixed**!

**I swapped my CAT.5e cable for a CAT.6 cable.**

I have no idea why this fixed it. I've tried two other CAT.5e cables I had lying around, and both had the same issue. Anyway, I hope this helps someone.